# string not auto-parsed to float on inserting into DataTable

Tags: c#, parsing, datatable, argumentexception

I have a `DataTable` with two columns of types: `DateTime` and `Single`.
I have a list of string `{ "2016-03-04T00:00:00.000-05:00", "0.1" }` which I want to push into this table as a `DataRow dr` using code:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (string s in myList) dr[i++] = s;
```

Exception is: *Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <0.1> in ... Column.  Expected type is Single.*

Why first value is correctly inserted while the second fails?

Comment: try to use "float" instead Single (or "double")

Comment: This is working fine for me - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bfr7si Can you [edit] and add the code for creating the DataTable?

Comment: Didn't know that you get the conversion automatically. I would use `DateTime.Parse` and `Single.Parse` myself.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?